# Bit fields giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure, scanf, bit-fields

This is C language. When I run my following program, no matter how small values I give, I get runtime segmentation fault error. Please help me find out the cause of this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct date
{
unsigned day:
    5;
unsigned month:
    4;
unsigned year:
    12;
};
struct emp
{
    char name[10];
    struct date d;
};
int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    struct emp *orderA = (struct emp *)a;
    struct emp *orderB = (struct emp *)b;
    return (  orderA->d.year - orderB->d.year  );
}
int main ()
{
    int i;
    struct emp e[5];
    for (i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %d %d", e[i].name, e[i].d.day, e[i].d.month, e[i].d.year);
    }
    qsort(e, 5, sizeof(struct emp), compare);
    for (i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d %d %d\n", e[i].name, e[i].d.day, e[i].d.month, e[i].d.year);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bitfields in C have a lot of quirks, so I would recommend that you avoid them unless you really need them. For above code you could use `struct date { uint8_t day; uint8_t month; uint16_t year; };`, and you likely get the same sized struct, which is equally or more performant, and more versatile (you can take address of members).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want `scanf()` to scan your stuff, you have to pass ***addresses*** of stuff, not the actual stuff.  (If you do not pass the address of something to `scanf()`, then how can `scanf()` store a value in it?)

Now, in C when you refer to an array such as `e[i].name` you are actually referring to the address of the first element of the array, so you do not have to do anything special about that.  (Besides to be careful to not enter more than 9 characters for name, wh00ps, that's extremely unsafe, be careful!)

But with integers, such as `e[i].d.day` etc, you can't just pass the `int` as it is, because `scanf()` expects pointers, so it will treat your `int` as a pointer to an `int`, so it will allow the user to enter a number, and then it will try to store the number at the location pointed by that pointer, which is just some random location in memory, and thus the segfault.

So, when you want to scan an `int`, you have to pass the address of the `int`, like this: `&e[i].d.day`

Except that when the integer is a field of a record, you cannot take its address, because it does not have an address of its own, it lives within some bits stored at an address.

So, I am afraid you are going to have to write a special function for reading those `struct date`s of yours, which will have to declare individual `int`s, pass their addresses to `scanf()`, and then store the resulting values in a `struct date`.